# Python 3.4 Syntax error and how to fix it

Tags: python, python-3.4, argument-unpacking

While the following line is accepted on Python 3.6, On Python 3.4 I am getting a syntax error:

```
struct.pack_into('q' * len(GeoFence_lat_list)*2,buff,264,*GeoFence_lat_list, *GeoFence_lon_list)
```

Where GeoFence_lon_list is an array declared as:

```
Geo_Fence_list = []
GeoFence_lat_list = []

GeoFence_lon_list = []
```

Here is more code to review:

```
if (Polygon_available_size == 0):
    buff = ctypes.create_string_buffer(workzone_size)
    struct.pack_into('q' * 33, buff, 0, Speed_limit, Speed_Zone_lat, Speed_Zone_longi, Speed_Zone_heading_radians,
            Speed_Zone_ITIS_CODE, Speed_Zone_2_lat, Speed_Zone_2_longi, Speed_Zone_2_heading_radians, Speed_Zone_2_ITIS_CODE,G20_lat, G20_longi,
            G20_heading_radians, G20_ITIS_CODE,W20_lat, W20_longi, W20_heading_radians ,W20_ITIS_CODE,W21_5BR_lat,W21_5BR_longi, W21_5BR_heading_radians,
            W21_5BR_ITIS_CODE,W21_5AR_lat,W21_5AR_longi, W21_5AR_heading_radians, W21_5AR_ITIS_CODE,First_Taper_lat,First_Taper_longi,
            Last_Taper_lat, Last_Taper_longi, 2020, 2456,60, Polygon_available_size)
elif (int(Polygon_available_size) > 0):
    geo_fence_size = struct.calcsize('q' * len(GeoFence_lat_list)*2)
    #print("geo_fence_size", geo_fence_size)
    workzone_size = workzone_size + geo_fence_size
    buff = ctypes.create_string_buffer(workzone_size)
    struct.pack_into('q' * 33, buff, 0, Speed_limit, Speed_Zone_lat, Speed_Zone_longi, Speed_Zone_heading_radians,
            Speed_Zone_ITIS_CODE, Speed_Zone_2_lat, Speed_Zone_2_longi, Speed_Zone_2_heading_radians, Speed_Zone_2_ITIS_CODE,G20_lat, G20_longi,
            G20_heading_radians, G20_ITIS_CODE,W20_lat, W20_longi, W20_heading_radians ,W20_ITIS_CODE,W21_5BR_lat,W21_5BR_longi, W21_5BR_heading_radians,
            W21_5BR_ITIS_CODE,W21_5AR_lat,W21_5AR_longi, W21_5AR_heading_radians, W21_5AR_ITIS_CODE,First_Taper_lat,First_Taper_longi,
            Last_Taper_lat, Last_Taper_longi, 2020, 2456,60, Polygon_available_size)
    struct.pack_into('q', * len(GeoFence_lat_list)*2,buff,264,*GeoFence_lat_list, *GeoFence_lon_list)
    GeoFence_lat_list.clear()
    GeoFence_lon_list.clear()
packed_flag = 1
```

Comment: could you please provide full error trace?

Comment: See [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), which was implemented for Python 3.5.

Comment: python 3.4 reach end-of-life over a year ago, you should upgrade if possible.

Comment: I am running on OpenWRT for ARM processor. It is difficult to upgrade to Python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.4 only allows one unpacked argument per call.

Your original code is using multiple unpackings simply to append multiple lists into the byte buffer. You can achieve the same thing simply by calling `struct.pack_into()` multiple times, with appropriate offsets for each part.

```
start = 264
struct.pack_into(str(len(GeoFence_lat_list)) + 'q', buff, start, *GeoFence_lat_list);
start += 8 * len(GeoFence_lat_list)
struct.pack_into(str(len(GeoFence_lon_list)) + 'q', buff, start, *GeoFence_lon_list);
```